# Retrofit + RxJava retry with different link

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I am using an Api which requires to queries:

1. Title of the Movie
2. Release Year of the Movie

But my other Api gives me only the release year for a specific country, so I might have to retry the request with + / - one year. With other words, if the first attemp Fails, I want to retry with a different link/ queries.

How can I achieve this using Retrofit and RxJava?

Comment: Check my answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275856/can-we-use-retrofit-rxjava-rxandroid-together/41287745#41287745

Comment: https://github.com/AnkitDroidGit/DaggerRxAdnroid A simple example of RxJava with Retfrofit in Android

Answer (score 0):

Try using *.switchIfEmpty()* operator.